# "contextual" one/two dwelling

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "contextual" in "[R-C2: contextual one/two dwelling; single detached, side-by-side and duplex homes. Single detached homes may include a secondary suite.](https://blog.calgaryluxuryhomesearch.com/2017/02/different-types-land-zoning-mean/)"?
Does it mean that whether or not a property is considered a one/two dwelling will depend on certain "context"? Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: This is hilarious—"If you are unfamiliar with each of the land use zoning titles mean, here’s a complete guide," followed by absolutely unintelligible specialized legal terms

Comment: It's clearly a specialized use in zoning law. Google "zoning contextual" seems to provide some helpful results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **[THE CITY OF CALGARY LAND USE BYLAW 1P2007](https://www.calgary.ca/pda/pd/calgary-land-use-bylaw-1p2007/calgary-land-use-bylaw-1p2007.html)** defines a number of terms including the word "contextual" being the adjectival form of the noun "context".

Please see the Cambridge dictionary definition of the noun "context" **[here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/context)**.

Here is an extract from the bylaw:

> (36) “contextual adjacent buildings” means the two closest buildings
> to a parcel:  (a) located on the same block face not separated by a
> street;  (b) in the case of low density residential district  where
> the building is on a parcel designated as a residential district;  (c)
> and where the building  is not an Accessory Residential Building.

"Contextual" here relates to the planning permission for a new building **in the context of** the two existing buildings between which the parcel of land is located. The proposed new building will be constructed on said parcel of land.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your explanations!